# Rails coded Product Designer app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, customization

I was just wondering if anyone knew anything gem, sources codes, or open-source apps which offer the ability to allow a user to Personalise/Customise specific products.

Much like 
NikeID: http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/c/nikeid
Or
Rolls Royce: http://www.rolls-roycemotorcars.com/phantom-family/phantom/configure/

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to *filters*, in that case you can use https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope which will help you write some less code in backend stuff.

Comment: I was looking for something more along the lines of a source code for a type of Product designer and customiser?